# Allow spoofing on postfix server

Tags: debian, postfix, smtp

I'm trying to set up help desk software which requires the ability to change the headers of a message (aka 'spoof' it). Right now, my mail server is configured to use SASL and requires authentication before a message can be sent.

When the helpdesk tries to change the message header, my postfix server won't send the message! I get a message saying that 'email address whatever@whatever is not owned by user user@mydomain'.

How can I tell postfix not to check the headers and to send anyway?

Comment: What header are they replacing exactly? Because your error sounds like you have `smtpd_sender_login_maps` enabled..

Answer (score 0):

You can implement header-checks in postfix. And you can make a content filter before the mails sent outside from postfix.

You can refer this [link](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) to know more about the hear-checks 
You can see an example [here](http://mattshaw.org/news/how-to-filter-mail-with-postfix-header_checks/)  for the header replacement. In the place of REDIRECT  you can use REPLACE with new headers